# What does the error message "w = 0 in Givens();" mean when trying curve fitting in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I keep having the `w = 0 in Givens();` error message when I try to use `gnuplot` built-in curve fitting feature.

What I do is trying to fit experimental data to a certain mathematical model in `gnuplot`.
I define the model function `s(x)`:

```
gnuplot> z(x)=(x-mu)/be
gnuplot> s(x)=(k/be)*exp(-z(x)-exp(-z(x)))
```

Then I plot the actual data and the model function to get an initial guess for the model parameters:

[image: initial]

Then I adjust the initial guess:

```
gnuplot> k=2.6; mu=-8.8; 
gnuplot> replot
```

To obtain a pretty fine picture:

[image: initial-adjusted]

Then I try to precisely fit the curve:

```
gnuplot> fit s(x) '701_707_TRACtdetq.log30.hist1.txt' u 2:6 via k,be,mu
```

And what I get is the single iteration and a error message:

```
 Iteration 0
 WSSR        : 3.85695           delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : 0
 delta(WSSR) : 0                 limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 0.223951

initial set of free parameter values

k               = 2.6
be              = 1
mu              = -8.8
/

 Iteration 1
 WSSR        : 0.0720502         delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -52.5315
 delta(WSSR) : -3.7849           limit for stopping : 1e-05
 lambda   : 0.0223951

resultant parameter values

k               = 2.03996
be              = 0.777868
mu              = -8.87082
         w = 0 in Givens();  Cjj = 3.37383e-196,  Cij = 2.54469e-192
```

And the curve pretty fit:

[image: fit]

What does that error means and how would I get the fit process going?

Comment: What happens when you don't use the scaling function z(x) (using the function directly in s(x)) ? What happens when you start with `be` far from the fitted value, say 1000 ? Same error in this blog post, but no infos : http://dany-nash.blogspot.fr/2013/02/fit-gnuplot-lineal-y-gausiano.html.

Comment: @Pascail: I think I figured out the problem: this happens when the fit reached the optimal values for the fit parameters, but the residuals are still too high for iterations to stop. Thus the internal matrix `C` yields zeroes (or very small values) as deltas for the next iteration. In my case, there is a tiny bump at approximately `x=-13` that prevents the convergence norm from reaching the convergence limit.

Comment: Great world of numerical instabilities... I think you can answer your own question now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `w = 0 in Givens();` seems to be related to inability of `fit` to perform the next iteration of fit parameters estimation. The error message is accompanied by the values of a certain matrix `C[][]` that is related to the direction of the next step of the fit iterations. Those values are usually very small, like in the example, `Cjj = 3.37383e-196,  Cij = 2.54469e-192`. This means that the fit process has converged to a state where every other local set of fit parameters are less optimal than the current (local state extreme), but the current residuals are above the convergence limit, in this case `delta(WSSR) : -3.7849           limit for stopping : 1e-05`. This happens when the data to be fitted exhibits a disturbance (at approximately `x=-13` in this case) that yields significant `delta` despite the perfect fit.

Long story short: the error usually happens when the fit is fine but the delta is still high.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm just about to say might seem strange but it works!

When I run into the 'w = 0 in Givens()' error I use:

```
gnuplot> set xrange [a,b]
```

where 'a' and 'b' are chosen to window the 'most interesting' parts.  If you now do the fitting command that you have:

```
gnuplot> fit s(x) '701_707_TRACtdetq.log30.hist1.txt' u 2:6 via k,be,mu
```

You might find that your fit now converges.  I'm not sure why 'set range' affects the fitting algorithm but it does!  In your example, I might let:

a = -12

b = -2

Comment: Yes, it helps because the fitting procedure now works withing range of values without a bump and thus converges.